# Lengths of infinite products of matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

The length of a matrix |A| defined as the square root of the sum of the squares of all its entries has the following property:

$|AB| \le |A||B|$

How to prove that $|A^k|\le|A|^k$ when k is infinite?

Comment: At first, you should clarify, how you define infinite exponentiation on Matrices. Also, if k is infinite, the right side of your inequality should also be infinite, unless abs(A) was smaller than 1.

Comment: An induction proof would work I think.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk induction proves that the statement holds for all **finite** values of $k$.  It's not clear what "when $k$ is infinite" is supposed to mean here, though.

Comment: @axioman By infinite exponentiation on Matrices, do you mean the meaning of $A^k$ when k is infinite? If so, I intended to mean the infinite matrix product $AAAA...$ where A is a square matrix. Assuming that the right hand side converges, could the inequality be proved when k is infinite?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  I intended to mean the infinite matrix product AAAA...,where A is a square matrix.

Comment: Case 1: abs(A)<1 the finite inequality shows abs(A^k)->0, so the infinite Product should be 0 (probably depends on your precise definition of infinite matrix products). So in a sense the inequality is 0<=0; if abs(A)>1, the right side is infinite, therefore, the inequality is always true in some sense.

Comment: The case where abs(A)=1 once again dependes on your definition of infinite matrix products, but if lim n->inf (abs(A)^n)=abs(A^k) for your infinite k, the inequality holds, because it holds for every finite n, and therefore also for the limit, if both exist (in this case the limit on the right is just 1)

Comment: @chen the proper terminology is not "$A^k$ when $A$ is infinite", just as it is meaningless to say $A^\infty$.  What you're **trying** to ask about, it seems, is $\lim_{k \to \infty}A^k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the following:

> Let $a_k,b_k$ denote sequences of real numbers with $k = 1,2,3,\dots$.  Suppose that $a_k \leq b_k$ for all values of $k$, and suppose that each sequence converges with $\lim_{k \to \infty}a_k = a$ and $\lim_{k \to \infty}b_k = b$.  It follows that $a \leq b$.

So, we have
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}|A^k| \leq \lim_{k \to \infty}|A|^k
$$
provided that both of these limits exist.